# ¿Cómo ordenar un Array de estructuras con varios elementos de acuerdo a un elemento en especifico usando qsort en C?

Tags: c, struct

### ¿Qué tengo?

Tengo una estructura con varios elementos de un mismo tipo

```
struct tipo_t
{
    char elemento_1[8192];
    char elemento_2[8192];
    char elemento_3[8192];
    char elemento_4[8192];
    .
    .
}
```

También tengo un array de estructuras de ese tipo (que leo y lleno por archivo)

```
tipo_t *array = malloc(longitud*sizeof(tipo_t));
array[longitud];
```

Luego lo ordeno usando la funcion **qsort()** de la libreria de **C**
cuya declaración es esta:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))
```

Y que para mi caso en particular queda de esta forma

```
qsort (array, longitud, sizeof(tipo_t), comparaPorElemento1);
```

Tengo una función de comparación para el elemento 1:

```
int comparaPorElemento1 (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  tipo_t *A = (tipo_t *)a;
  tipo_t *B = (tipo_t *)b;
  return ( strcmp( B->elemento_1, A->elemento_1 ) );
}
```

### ¿Qué quiero?

Ahora lo que quiero es poder seleccionar por cual elemento ordenar el array de estructuras. no solo por el elemento 1 sino por cualquiera de los elementos, luego de buscar por varios sitios de internet la respuesta que obtuve fue que tenia que hacer una función de comparación por cada elemento a comparar, y aunque esta solución *funciona* me preguntaba si no habría otra manera.

Pensé que tal vez podría agregar otro  elemento a la estructura que fuera el elemento a comparar

```
struct tipo_t
{
    char elemento_1[8192];
    char elemento_2[8192];
    char elemento_3[8192];
    char elemento_4[8192];
    .
    .
    char comparate[8192];
}
```

Y que previo a la instrucción de qsort seleccionara el elemento a comparar y lo intercambiara por el elemento *comparate*, sin embargo me parece que eso disminuiría el desempeño del programa. Así que trate de pensar en alguna manera de que la copia hacia el elemento *comparate* se hiciese rápidamente y pensé que  con **uniones** podría pasar algo, pero abandone esa idea porque no creo que pueda hacer nada por allí.

Hacer las funciones de comparación no es tampoco nada a lo cual temer, porque es básicamente unos cuantos ctrl+c ctrl+v, pero ustedes entenderán que esta bien preguntar si no hay otra manera.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo una solución.

Por lo que veo, tu `strut` no es mas que un conjunto de cadenas, todas del mismo tamaño. Así que puedes usar un *desplazamiento* dentro de la estructura para seleccionar la cadena a comparar.

**No lo he probado**, pero, salvo cambios mínimos, debería de funcionar.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

// MUY IMPORTANTE usar el nombre del tipo CORRECTO 'struct tipo_t'
#define setCompareOffset( ELEL ) ( compareElementOffset = offsetof( struct tipo_t, ELEL ) )

size_t compareElementOffset = 0;

int comparaPorElemento( const void *a, const void *b ) {
  const char *A = ( (const char *)a ) + compareElementOffset;
  const char *B = ( (const char *)b ) + compareElementOffset;

  return strcmp( A, B );
}
```

Tal y como está, compara por el primer elemento.

Para indicar *otro* elemento, hacemos

```
setCompareOffset( elemento_3 );
```

A partir de ese momento, las comparaciones se harían comparando el `elemento_3` de la estructura.

Esta solución **es esclusiva** para tu `struct`, que, como dije, no es mas que un grupo de campos del mismo tipo.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, y funciona perfecto. (tal como estaba anteriormente) ahora no se tendría que probarlo de nuevo

Comment: Si te funciona, déjalo. El cambio es para usar 1 solo argumento en `setCompareOffset( )`. O cámbialo; al gusto del consumidor :-)

Comment: Si, no debe tener ningún problema, lo veo claramente. Me tarde en comprobar la solucion porque olvide agragar la libreria correspondiente `#include <stddef.h>`

Comment: Se que no se estila por características del sitio pero MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: @JacoboCórdova he editado la respuesta, a ver si ahora te gusta mas ;-)

Comment: Si, cuando estuve leyendo la definición de offsetof, pensé que en realidad funcionaría una solucion _de este otro tipo_ solo que tendrian que ser todos char, o en todo caso la mente se me fue a c++ y pense en sobbrecarga de operadores para hacer una sola funcion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58102/discussion-between-jacobo-cordova-and-trauma).